# jQuery : Move data of a table to another table

Tags: jquery

I need to move data of a table which are selected with checkbox to another table. Likewise we can remove from the 2nd table, then the removed item will come back to the master table. I have done this with my basic knowledge on `jQuery`. But I'm not satisfied on my work. Being a `jQuery` beginner, I think this can be done more efficiently. I need some ideas from experts..

thanking in advance.

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
$("body").on('click', '.loadStu', function(e){      

    var rowCount = $('.newClsStuList tr').length;
    var i = rowCount;       
    $(".stuList:checked").each(function(){

        var stuFulDetl =  $(this).data("value");
        stuDetl = stuFulDetl.split('|'); 
        //alert (stuDetl[3]);
        $('#stuLoadList_'+stuDetl[3]).remove();
        var stuList = '<tr id="stListTr_'+ i +'"><td> '+ i +'</td>';
        stuList += '<td> '+stuDetl[1]+'</td>';
        stuList += '<td> '+stuDetl[2]+'</td>';
        stuList += '<td> &nbsp; <a href="" class="remStu" id="stList_'+i+'" data-value="'+ i +'|' + stuFulDetl+' "> remove </a> </td> </tr>';

        $('.newClsStuList').append(stuList).slideDown('slow');
        $('#stListTr_'+ i).hide().fadeIn("slow");
        i++ ;
    });     


    var k = 1;
    var chkBxDet ;
    $('.ClsStuList').find('tr:not(.thClas)').each(function (j, el) {

        var $tds = $(this).find('td');            

        if($tds.eq(1).text() != ''){
            var x = 1;
            var nwchkBxDet = '';                
            var chkBxDet = $('#stuHidn_'+ $tds.eq(0).text().trim()).val();
            //var ck = '#stuHidn_'+($tds.eq(0).text()).trim() ;
            //alert($tds.eq(1).text() + ' - '+ $tds.eq(0).text() + ' - '+  j  + ' - '+ ck + '  hidn : '+  chkBxDet);
            chkBxDet = chkBxDet.split('|');


            while(x < 4){
                var ml = x -1 ;
                nwchkBxDet += chkBxDet[ml] +'|';
                x++ ;           
            }
            nwchkBxDet +=  k ;
            var newChkBx = '<input type="checkbox" name="stu_id[]" class="stuList" data-value="'+ nwchkBxDet + '" />';
            var hidnFild = '<input type="hidden" id="stuHidn_'+ k +'" value="'+ nwchkBxDet + '" />';
            $('#stuLoadList_'+k).remove();
            var stuList = '<tr id="stuLoadList_'+ k +'"><td> '+ k +'</td>';
            stuList += '<td> '+$tds.eq(1).html()+'</td>';
            stuList += '<td  align="center"  width="40px"> '+newChkBx+' ' + hidnFild + '</td> </tr>';

            $('.ClsStuList').append(stuList);
            $('#stuLoadList_'+ k ).hide().fadeIn("slow");
            k++;
        }
        $(this).remove();

    });

});




$('body').on('click','.remStu', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();         

    var countOfStu = $('.ClsStuList tr').length ;   

    var fulDet = $(this).data("value");
    var fulDetAry = fulDet.split('|');
    var remID = fulDetAry[0].trim();
    var nwchkBxDet = fulDetAry[1]+'|'+fulDetAry[2]+'|'+fulDetAry[3]+'|'+countOfStu;


    var stuNam = fulDetAry[2]+' - '+fulDetAry[1];
    var newChkBx = '<input type="checkbox" name="stu_id[]" class="stuList" data-value="'+ nwchkBxDet + '" />';
    var hidnFild = '<input type="hidden" id="stuHidn_'+ countOfStu +'" value="'+ nwchkBxDet + '" />';
    var stuList = '<tr id="stuLoadList_'+countOfStu +'"><td> '+ countOfStu +'</td>';
    stuList += '<td> '+stuNam+'</td>';
    stuList += '<td  align="center"  width="40px"> '+newChkBx+' ' + hidnFild + '</td> </tr>';
    $('.ClsStuList').append(stuList);

    $('#stListTr_'+remID).remove();



    $('.newClsStuList').find('tr:not(.thClas)').each(function (i, el) {

        var $tds = $(this).find('td');          
        var k = i + 1;

        if(  $tds.eq(1).text() != ''){
            var rowNo = $tds.eq(0).text().trim();               
            var remDet = $('#stList_'+rowNo).data("value");
            var remDetArry = remDet.split('|');
            $('#stListTr_'+rowNo).remove();

            var x = 1;
            var ckBxDet = k;
            while(x < 4){                   
                ckBxDet += '|'+remDetArry[x];                   
                x++;
            }

            var stuList = '<tr id="stListTr_'+k +'"><td> '+ k +'</td>';
            stuList += '<td> '+$tds.eq(1).text()+'</td>';
            stuList += '<td> '+$tds.eq(2).text()+'</td>';
            stuList += '<td> &nbsp; <a href="#" class="remStu" id="stList_'+k+'" data-value="'+ ckBxDet +'"> remove </a> </td> </tr>';

            $('.newClsStuList').append(stuList);
            $('#stListTr_'+ k).hide().fadeIn("slow");
        }

    });
});
```

});

http://jsfiddle.net/nsk21/73z9f00g/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you've done is okay, but you can use jQuery and select larger groups of objects instead of manipulating all the data of the children. A more elegant solution can be found by copying/removing the table row instead of finding the values of all of the columns and using an array as you have done above.

Something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/73z9f00g/4/

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("body").on('click', '.loadStu', function(e){
        fade = false;
        $(".ClsStuList td input:checked").each(function(){
            tr = $(this).parent().parent();
            tr.append($("<td>", {
                class:"remStu",
                html:"Remove",
                style:"text-decoration:underline;cursor:pointer"
            }));
            tr.find("input:checked").attr("checked", false);
            $(".newClsStuList").append(tr.clone());
            tr.remove();
            fade = true;
        });
        if (fade) FadeIn();
    })

    $("body").on('click', '.remStu', function(e){
        tr = $(this).parent();
        tr.find(".remStu").remove();
        $(".ClsStuList").append(tr.clone());
        tr.remove();
        FadeIn();
    })
});

function FadeIn(){
    $(".ClsStuList, .newClsStuList").hide().fadeIn();
};
```

Comment: See updated fiddle for sorting (when you add the student back in, it will sort in order): http://jsfiddle.net/73z9f00g/8/

Comment: i don't need sorting (but thanks for the idea).. in my case i need the number series in both cases... according to what i have done in my first fiddle..